# Using Validation Plugin, how can i submit form when either one of the checkbox is checked or specific text field is not empty

Tags: ajax, jquery-validate

//Using Validation Plugin, how can i submit form when either one of the checkbox is checked or specific text field is not empty? I have checkboxes which generates dynamically and category_name text field. I want to submit form when either one of the checkbox is checked or category_name text field is not empty...

```
<?php
            while($cat_row = "fetch_result"){
                $tr.='<b><input type="checkbox" class="required" name="category[]" value="'.$cat_row['category_name'].'" id="category[]" checked/>'.$cat_row['category_name'].'</b>';
            }
            ?>
        //HTML File

<body>  
<form id="abc" name="abc" action="PATH_TO_PHPFILE" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >        

            <div id="cd">
                <?=$tr?>
                <div id="err"></div>
            </div>  
            <input type="text" name="category_name" id="category_name" class="text_box" value="" />
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("form").validate({
        rules:{
            category:{
                required:true,
                minlength:2
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo('#err');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            var options = {

                success:function (data){

                    $.unblockUI();
                  //do something
                },
                beforeSubmit:function (){
                    //do something
                }
            };
            $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    }); 
}); 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: issue is if i set "class=required" in checkboxes and textfield then it will not submit form until both have some value but i want to submit if one of the two has some value!